# « Mal à la France » : sens, origine

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, connotation

Ces derniers jours l'expression « mal à la France » à pu être entendue, et il est évident qu'elle est comprise par certains (je ne l'avais jamais entendue). On la trouve dans un [commentaire de Kylian Mbappé](https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2023/06/28/du-footballeur-kylian-mbappe-au-rappeur-niska-les-reactions-indignees-a-la-mort-de-nahel-se-multiplient_6179579_3224.html), qui l'adapte en disant « J'ai mal à ma France ». Ensuite, on peut l'entendre dans le parler d'une manifestante, qui dit « J'ai mal à cette France-là » : « [reportage : « Ça aurait pu être mon enfant », au point 2 mn 18 s »](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/other/mort-de-nahel-l-attitude-de-sa-m%C3%A8re-lors-de-la-marche-blanche-%C3%A0-nanterre-n-a-rien-d-%C3%A9tonnant/ar-AA1dgfDv?ocid=msedgdhphdr&pc=U531&cvid=27404da775b14bb291b6d0a3e3d12b7c&ei=26).

On trouve également que c'est une expression qui sert au titre d'un livre par Marcel Bigeart, [*J'ai Mal à la France*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=mal+%C3%A0+la+France), paru en 2001, un titre qui pourrait être l'origine de l'expression ; au vu des questions de torture que le livre soulève, on se demande si l'expression telle que trouvée actuellement n'aurait pas des connotations caustiques.

On ne trouve pas « mal à la France » dans le Wiktionnaire.

Est-ce que quelqu'un saurait si l'expression remonte au livre de 2001 ? Si elle vient bien du livre, quel sens lui donne-t-on dans le livre ?

Enfin, est-ce que quelqu'un saurait ce qu'elle signifie aujourd'hui et si employée par les personnes que je cite, en particulier, on devrait la comprendre comme étant chargée de connotations ? Lesquelles ?

Comment expliquer les deux usages particuliers qui sont considérés ci-dessus (*ma* France, *cette* France-là) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La premier emploi de l'expression que je connaisse est dans une lettre de Michelet écrite en 1854 et citée par Gabriel Monod dans *Michelet et l'Italie*.  Dans *Le discours amoureux* Roland Barthes cite la phrase de Michelet en exemple dans le chapitre « J'ai mal à l'autre » ([p.69](http://palimpsestes.fr/textes_philo/barthes/Barthes_Fragments1977.pdf)) dans une analyse centrée sur l'identification à autrui, la compassion et la souffrance.

Même si à l'entrée *avoir mal à* du [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maux) on trouve un exemple de 1980 pour illustrer l'expression (*Le mal à la France atteint à l'aigu quand le Canard enchaîné (...) orchestre depuis son officine le débat public (Le Figaro Magazine*, 26 avr. 1980, p. 21), et que dans son livre  *De la France considérée comme une maladie* (Flammarion, 1982) l'académicien Jean Dutourd prend la peine de s'y étendre :

> Quand on est français il ne se passe pas de jour qu'on n'éprouve une douleur quelque part. D'où l'expression naïve et ridicule : « J'ai mal à la France. » Je n'imagine pas un Chinois disant qu'il a mal à la Chine, ni un Zurichois ayant mal à la Suisse. Je suppose que cela est dû à l'ancienneté de la France en tant que nation.

c'est probablement le livre de B. qui l'a en quelque sorte popularisée car elle est depuis une vingtaine d'années reprise régulièrement dans les media. Je ne lui connais pas plusieurs sens, que ce soit « ma France » ou « la France », il s'agit toujours de la souffrance infligée à l'idée que le locuteur se fait de la France.

> c'est pourquoi, comme beaucoup de mes concitoyens, j'ai mal à la France ou, du moins, à une certaine idée de la France.
> (Dominique Bromberger dans *Le Monde* du  22/02/2011)

Comment: J'enlèverais la dernière citation, parce qu'elle contient un jugement de valeur qui n'est pas nécessaire.

Comment: La signification serait donc « souffrance, ou plutôt déception, résultant d'une différence de point de vue qu'entraine une idée dépréciative qu'on vient d'acquérir  de la France, cette différence étant relative au point de vue globale, prétendument satisfaisant, qu'on en avait avant que cette nouvelle réalité n'ajoute une mauvaise impression ».

Comment: C'est un peu évident ... quelle autre signification aurait été possible?

Answer (score 2):

C'est tout simplement une reprise de l'expression commune "avoir mal à X" où X est une partie de son corps: "En voiture, j'ai mal à la tête", "Après cette randonnée, elles avaient mal aux pieds", etc.

Ici on considère la France comme une partie de son propre corps, sous-entendu: on est tellement français qu'on éprouve la même douleur quand le pays ne va pas bien que si c'était une partie de son propre corps.

Cette expression suit une construction grammaticale logique, il semble donc probable que plusieurs personnes l'aient "inventée" indépendamment.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147010/discussion-on-answer-by-anne-aunyme--mal-a-la-france--sens-origine); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.